# Typescript function overloads not working for the union type case

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble getting function overloads to work properly in Typescript.

I have a simple union type and a function that can handle either type. I've created overloads to handle each of them independently.

```
type A = { type: "a", x: number }
type B = { type: "b", x: number, y: number }

type Z = A | B

function f(z: A): { x: number, y: undefined }
function f(z: B): {x: number, y: number}
function f(z: Z) {
    if (z.type === "a") {
        return {x: z.x, y: undefined}
    } else {
        return {x: z.x, y: z.y}
    }
}
```

It appears to work as well.

```
// This works
const a = f({ type: "a", x: 1 })
const b = f({ type: "b", x: 1, y: 1 })
```

However, when it comes to using it with a disambiguated union type, it doesn't work.

```
// Why doesn't this work?
function g(z: Z) {
    const x = f(z) 
}

// This also doesn't work.
function h<T extends Z>(z: T) {
    const x = f(z) 
}
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'Z' is not assignable to parameter of type 'B'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Property 'y' is missing in type 'A'.
```

Seems like it might user error, but also seems kind of like a bug...

Here's a [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Z%20%3D%20A%20%7C%20B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f(z%3A%20A)%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20undefined%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20f(z%3A%20B)%3A%20%7Bx%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%7D%0D%0Afunction%20f(z%3A%20Z)%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(z.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22a%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7Bx%3A%20z.x%2C%20y%3A%20undefined%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7Bx%3A%20z.x%2C%20y%3A%20z.y%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20works%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20f(%7B%20type%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20x%3A%201%20%7D)%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20f(%7B%20type%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%201%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Why%20doesn't%20this%20work%3F%0D%0Afunction%20g(z%3A%20Z)%20%7B%0D%0A%09const%20x%20%3D%20f(z)%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20also%20doesn't%20work.%0D%0Afunction%20h%3CT%20extends%20Z%3E(z%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%09const%20x%20%3D%20f(z)%20%0D%0A%7D) to check try it yourself. Make sure to turn strictNullChecks on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloaded function implementation is not taken into account when compiler does overload resolution. You have to add an explicit overload declaration for `Z` argument type, for exapmle like this:

```
function f(z: Z): {x: number, y: number | undefined};
```

The complete code is

```
type A = { type: "a", x: number }
type B = { type: "b", x: number, y: number }

type Z = A | B

function f(z: A): { x: number, y: undefined }
function f(z: B): { x: number, y: number}
function f(z: Z): { x: number, y: number | undefined}
function f(z: Z) {
    if (z.type === "a") {
        return {x: z.x, y: undefined}
    } else {
        return {x: z.x, y: z.y}
    }
}

const a = f({ type: "a", x: 1 })
const b = f({ type: "b", x: 1, y: 1 })


function g(z: Z) {
    const x = f(z) 
}

function h<T extends Z>(z: T) {
    const x = f(z) 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem in the playground. In fact, I think its an actual bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107

Comment: That issue is about making the explicit overload unnecessary. But the explicit overload usually works. I've updated the answer with complete code, there is no error in that code in the playground. Which error are you getting?

Comment: Oh, interesting. I see what you did there. So bizarre that it doesn't just use the function definition itself haha.