# Typescript overloaded function with enum argument does not accept the union of enum values

Tags: typescript, enums, overloading

This is probably because of my misunderstanding of how enums work in Typescript but I find it very unintuitive nonetheless.

In a library I am using, there is an overloaded function with the exact same signature, the only difference is that the first signature uses one member of the enum type as argument, and the other one uses the other member.

I can't seem to call this function with union of the enum members. If I use the number literals of the enum members to call the function, it is fine. See simplified example here:

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEIB2BXAtvAgjA5gFQE8AHBAbwCh4r4AxASQCUBlPeAXngEYAaS6pgKIBhAPIA5ACLt4AJnIBfcuVCRYCAGYokYAC4BLAPZJ4YOFB0gAFEihoQALngBnHTD1Ic3eAaL6jTx2x8YhAAOnpmPABKR1Q0ACMQGABuZXBoOHhNbT9jUxBzKxs7Rxc3Dy8fXICsXEISUMFRSRj4OMSUpQB6LoA9ft6seIMANwQ9J3gIPXiYWAITA1ByHoAhEAgDAHd4Cfg7eFcCdxxDg3gUJ3GdJXzCywAiKCdgB68g+rCIlijk+B6tgYYABrJzkO4WR7PV7vOohRrCcQSX7-LqAkFg8FmSFPF5veAAWXMAAtQnMkMADGhLFF4AAeeAABlCAFZ4AB+LjwRwyFEAoGgrEFHHQ-FEnSk8mU6m0hnMtmcj7w76sQJwhpNJF8roCBgMEQMJQQEA6bxIBAcJUNFWpY2mnSA6RWsKaySpCFWXEwwkkslQClUmn0pmsjlmhA87XowUeqF4rziyX+6VBuWhzmcbmHQFRgVg2NesW+qWB2UhhXhrMOgza3X6hhAA)

```
declare enum ArgType {
    FIRST = 1,
    SECOND = 2
}

declare function create(name: string, options: ArgType.FIRST): number;
declare function create(name: string, options: ArgType.SECOND): number;

//^^^^ Above is library code
//Below is me trying to use it

create("asd", ArgType.FIRST); //works
create("asd", ArgType.SECOND); //works

create("asd", Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2); //works
create("asd", Math.random() < 0.5 ? ArgType.FIRST : ArgType.SECOND); //ERROR

let one = ArgType.FIRST;
let two = ArgType.SECOND;
create("asd", Math.random() < 0.5 ? one : 2); //works
create("asd", Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : two); //works
create("asd", Math.random() < 0.5 ? one : two); //ERROR
```

Can someone please explain the behavior here and tell me how I can call this create function conditionally with either `ArgType.FIRST` or `ArgType.SECOND` without hardcoding the numbers at the call site?

Comment: I think this is the related typescript issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Why does an overloaded function declaration sometimes force useless type narrowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70146081/) [Typescript function overloads not working for the union type case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222428/) [How to pass a compatible union type from one overloaded function to another in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596397/) [Handling union with an overloaded function that doesn't handle the whole union within a single overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198641)

Answer (score 0):

Your second parameter in that "error line" is:
`Math.random() < 0.5 ? ArgType.FIRST : ArgType.SECOND`
Typescript types that as `ArgType`.

`ArgType` is not a valid parameter for the defined `create` function overloads.

You can work around that issue, by converting the argument to a `Number`, or using an `as`:

```
create("asd", Number(Math.random() < 0.5 ? ArgType.FIRST : ArgType.SECOND));
create("asd", (Math.random() < 0.5 ? ArgType.FIRST : ArgType.SECOND) as number);
```

That will force TS into interpreting the parameter as a value of that enum.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add another overload, you could add following and then it will accept a union type:

```js
declare function create(name: string, options: ArgType.FIRST | ArgType.SECOND): number;
```

You could also wrap it into a custom function:

```js
const wrappedCreate = (name: string, options: ArgType.FIRST | ArgType.SECOND) => {
    return options === ArgType.FIRST ? create(name, options) : create(name, options)
}
wrappedCreate("asd", Math.random() < 0.5 ? ArgType.FIRST : ArgType.SECOND);
```

Or you may use typecasting instead of the ternary operator

```js
const wrappedCreate = (name: string, options: ArgType.FIRST | ArgType.SECOND) {
    return create(name, options as ArgType.FIRST)
}
```