# Why does an overloaded function declaration sometimes force useless type narrowing?

Tags: typescript

Given the following implementation of an overloaded function statement:

```
function foo(options: "a"): "a";
function foo(options: "b"): "b";
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b" {
    switch (options) {
        case "a":
            return `a`;
        case "b":
        default:
            return `b`;
    }
}
```

I can call the function like this:

```
// this works
const url1 = foo("a");
const url2 = foo("b");
```

However, I get a type error if I call the `foo` function when being called with a value of union type `"a" | "b"`:

```
// function call (inside of wrapped function)
type Options = "a" | "b";
const wrapper = (options: Options) => {
    // function overloading forces the caller to narrow the type
    const url = foo(options); // Error: Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
}
```

I can fix this via

```
function foo(options: "a"): "a";
function foo(options: "b"): "b";
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b" {
    switch (options) {
        case "a":
            return "a";
        case "b":
        default:
            return "b";
    }
}

type Options = "a" | "b";
const wrapper = (options: Options) => {
    // Solution: Calling function 'foo' in the exact same way
    const url = options === "a" ? foo(options) : foo(options);
}
```

**Question**: Why does TypeScript force me to narrow the `options` value since it has no implication on how I call `foo`?

I always call `foo` as `foo(options)`. If the type signatures of the overloads differ in a greater way, for example, if some overloads contain optional parameter values, TS should of course prompt me to narrow the type. But shouldn't it infer that it's not necessary in a scenario as this one?

[TypeScript Playground of my question](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbhATgGwPYgBMBRTTXTJAbwCgk6kB6BpAMwFdh4AXAS12CQ8wMbBEjAuIXv1r12naQJa5cAClwxFUAFxIARCD0BKXQb0BuWXXnc+Sles12d+gEbHT7y-VYdb-VgcNLVNDJAAfNw99MMi9dyorHyQoAHceLngACyRHLSNE5KKkeBAoZDNtJOLkzAguNkwBAAMQZu8a+lLyqKrO+gIIFhA2bC4+-tr6xpbXdur6AF8k5aSmJC4snigkVPIAaygk+H4oLiRG7ABGJABeQLUzIw66E+Azi5wAJjuH1XjjJY1swbIoSiBsNhcjx3jxBkhcCxdpgQDAYBACL4FHYjEkuABPdGoJynX5mCJRF4lU7nVIotFYX55Zy6FAk94FW4APkKxXWoLsCIwOHwBBhAHNAphEDtNshSpDGVxcEhQKRcKkNllkAT0QtXjTPlD7so1MFnM9GMwSGRMLoACqE5AAcjMzsEO2AuHOZSgPHFoFcog2Kt1LoBzoAdCtqKtQJBYAhkOgsHhCAB1A47Gg+AUBU3M06haJmKl5+xm9kuAEmSlJct-c1FmJ6Ck14tthI54ppDLZXJNjm8-rdCqGCaTeh1BpNFtUmqj3r65KDYajcbLmrTmZ1mrLHyrHxh4laMmxXddQ101Hoij3QvvVlVzk87tFdYAZVw2DYil0AGEIWwCUsX8ARnVNd0YS1ZAIAADwQc4oHAZBUhAfFlzeD5Ll+QcdluAiWyQAB+RtnyQXQCzw54Y1Wah42gOBEFQYU0wITNMEOH431AsEqKrYta1Les-D4oIBKiISvGBJAvx-P8kHtLZZS2TBMQbP0AykRpkG2JBELYID8VVb19IEGEuAgYBBkxNgekRQQuGjXNRMFfiQiIuJ3CE88ATLVz83EjzyS8ktfK7Zde0yHIHygAoeIXMoxz0CdJyQbdZ2EydFwBVKalXEYxjyyYMoEPzl33JZqDxJ0T2cM9W1CqksNpelbyZPCn3yO5X2XT9v1-OwAKAkCGwglQoIEOUkHgxCUhQ3Z0Mww0cJNIKLSpZZliAA)

Comment: You have two call signatures, neither of which supports a union argument.  Are you asking why the *implementation signature* isn't also seen as a call signature? Or are you asking why the pair of call signatures together doesn't allow a union?  If it's the former, then the existing answer applies.  If it's the latter, then you're asking about [ms/TS#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) which isn't a feature of TS (yet?).

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I'm asking about the latter. The two call signatures I defined cover the two scenarios the function should be used for. Adding an additional call signature (i.e. Nicholas Tower's answer) which doesn't reflect a proper use case of the function is not a solution I'm seeking. As mentioned at the end of my question, I sometimes want that TS forces me to narrow my types and not just "hide" such type issues via the addition of an (in my view) "artificial" call signature.

Comment: @jcalz Given that TS#14107 isn't a feature of TS (yet), is an addition of a third call signature to eliminate the compiler error justifiable, even though I'd only add it because of this "deficiency" of the compiler?

Comment: I'd say it's justifiable; the TS team doesn't consider this a bug, just a feature that hasn't been implemented.  Right now the way to proceed is either to add a third call signature or change your call signature to something [generic](https://tsplay.dev/mqQpkm) which distributes over unions.  I'm happy to write this stuff up as an answer if it meets your needs; otherwise let me know if there's still something missing.

Comment: @jcalz I like the solution with the generic! It looks very elegant to me. It describes the relationship between the input and the output of the function, and at the same time makes it possible not to write a third function signature. 
Thanks! I think that would fully answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, the `foo()` function has two call signatures, neither of which accept a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `"a" | "b"`.  When you call an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the compiler checks each call signature in turn until it either finds *one* that works, or it fails to find any applicable call signature and produces an error.  Since there is no single call signature that accepts `"a" | "b"`, you get an error if you call it with such a union type.

You are not the first person to expect that the compiler should be able to select *multiple* call signatures when resolving call to overloaded functions.  Perhaps the compiler could possibly automatically *synthesize* call signatures accepting unions of other call signatures' parameter lists.  There is a relatively longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) asking for this.

For the foreseeable future, though, this is just how it is.

---

Right now, if you want the compiler to accept a union, you need to add a call signature for it.  Since you currently have 2 signatures, turning that into 3 by adding the missing union signature at the end  is a reasonable approach:

```
// call signatures
function foo(options: "a"): "a";
function foo(options: "b"): "b";
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b";
// implementation
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b" {
    switch (options) {
        case "a":
            return `a`;
        case "b":
        default:
            return `b`;
    }
}
```

If you have  independent call signatures and you want to represent every possible set of them (except for the empty set), you would have to turn that  into 2-1.  That gets very big very quickly:

```
// call signatures
function foo(options: "a"): "a";
function foo(options: "b"): "b";
function foo(options: "c"): "C";
function foo(options: "d"): "Δ";
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b";
function foo(options: "a" | "c"): "a" | "C";
function foo(options: "a" | "d"): "a" | "Δ";
function foo(options: "b" | "c"): "b" | "C";
function foo(options: "b" | "d"): "b" | "Δ";
function foo(options: "c" | "d"): "C" | "Δ";
function foo(options: "a" | "b" | "c"): "a" | "b" | "C";
function foo(options: "a" | "b" | "d"): "a" | "b" | "Δ";
function foo(options: "a" | "c" | "d"): "a" | "C" | "Δ";
function foo(options: "b" | "c" | "d"): "b" | "C" | "Δ";
function foo(options: "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"): "a" | "b" | "C" | "Δ";
// impl
function foo(options: "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"): "a" | "b" | "C" | "Δ" {
    switch (options) {
        case "a": return `a`;
        case "b": return `b`;
        case "c": return `C`;
        case "d": return `Δ`;
    }
}

const ret = foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "c" : "d");
ret; // const ret: "C" | "Δ"
```

Not great.

---

Instead, you could decide to write a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature to represent what you're doing:

```
function foo<T extends "a" | "b">(options: T): T;
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b" {
    switch (options) {
        case "a":
            return `a`;
        case "b":
        default:
            return `b`;
    }
}
```

Since `T` can be specified by `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"a" | "b"`, then the output automatically behaves as you desire.  This scales rather easily to larger cases also, although you need to write out the transformation in some other way.  If your inputs are all keylike types (like `"a"` and `"b"`) this can be an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
interface IOMap {
    a: "a";
    b: "b";
    c: "C";
    d: "Δ";
}
function foo<T extends keyof IOMap>(options: T): IOMap[T];
function foo(options: keyof IOMap): IOMap[keyof IOMap] {
    switch (options) {
        case "a": return `a`;
        case "b": return `b`;
        case "c": return `C`;
        case "d": return `Δ`
    }
}

const ret = foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "c" : "d");
ret; // const ret: "C" | "Δ"
```

But even in the case where you can't do that, you can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to convert an arbitrary input-output relationship into something that behaves appropriately in the face of unions:

```
function foo<T extends "a" | "b" | "c" | "d">(options: T):
    T extends "a" ? "a" :
    T extends "b" ? "b" :
    T extends "c" ? "C" :
    T extends "d" ? "Δ" :
    never
    ;
function foo(options: "a" | "b" | "c" | "d") {
    switch (options) {
        case "a": return `a`;
        case "b": return `b`;
        case "c": return `C`;
        case "d": return `Δ`
    }
}

const ret = foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "c" : "d");
ret; // const ret: "C" | "Δ"
```

Note how these scale linearly, so that  originally independent call signatures result in a single generic call signature which requires space that's some constant multiple of  to write.  So depending on your needs, this would be my suggestion instead of adding overloads.

---

Just as an aside: in none of these can the compiler actually check that the `switch`/`case` implementation satisfies the specified call signatures.  It isn't able to perform this sort of higher order analysis.  So you need to be careful with your implementation no matter what.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=99&ssc=16&pln=98&pc=16#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbgGwCZSQbwCglikB6UpeEDDJKASwHNQAXAVwCdoiSAzN4PBb0A9sCS8RIgBQiYwsVABcSAEQhVAShXrVAbh7F+gheMky5p5WoBGWnXYMkJAoaLNTZ899d1IAPrb2ahoBQU4k5Ej0YDAYEJDALCCmhi4m7hKelj46oYGqdtohqmGFpYTOzlAA7vQs8AAWSF5WmvhpVSRUUMi6Sp1dVVzsHOIABiDjEUPdIL1BA7POWBC8IGwYLEvLXSOcEzbTg8QAvmnnaVEsjfS4NSIcANZQafCKLEicGACMSAC8WRkuk0M0oHy+HAwACYAUDpOVQQQrhRjG4xJRqLRpPRgAxVkgRLwkDUOCAYDAIFh0ujgJo0iwAJ6U1DeRRwvwFRxvCGk8mUjhw1q5VltAEAPg6s3eeM+3zh5mFiiRznOl1AkFgCGQKCJUsiFCoNDoTFYnG4zjRpnhOUUeWCujBVsyitteIcDu5ltc1tdbPdangDoAwvo0s6MX6rDosA7ACnAYe9GUj2X9vnyQWKnPC4Z9LtT0ZKZSDWYzqlDTrzKYsaftZVjpdKBQTleTHhrhfKxc9TbUFdzbZttaC9Z7ZRbA9pQ87QdHWdD48TfCr7aVAezXYKJbrXN75aXRhX05FG7sc53I+bB5pvoLJ7Ls4KDYv+8XranUZPZ63e+fl77e4TkmH53naRa7t257gf+r5XmCUQxHEk63h2957t+ga-g6ZYYbBagJvqXS1PUTQtG6UDtJUuyYgs-RIPsYxIJMxzUTRfR2CoDGHCx1E9H0QacRAowTMGPG7HxaixoJwlMXG4wnEg5yqsizgylAnwjAqngALIpI0AB0ZLAFgIhgNI7QADxIAADPpACsSAAPyYUgMZaGCIx6GQhoQiMOgLleyIokgNx3CSjwvDysqQr8WnAhoKrdBC3ywoCiqIgYwURuIRrYri+LIHqfIUlSN7uPSzhMiyKBphyOF7o+knXmpnzFQKQrkSoNViv8kpUV0LUxXFa4UWCarIhq0BwIgSAAOIQMAEAcPQ8CEWV1YWQAKkgEAAB4sAtODQeU4ojSom3FJt74oWdx1FC+Z79VUxENM0I2UQpqnzH0Gg7KxxBcUxUxgtK32LJ9JCrOsmzbBDexCQcTFHCDJBKajKkGiFtz3BFryqclUJ-GlnggmCg0pcNGUY8QUTZZixo4ni9AEkVZIldS2UVSQVU6rVgKns1vJs+1gK3d1PjtL1a349F8rE6hypjcilwEJNWozQAksZe24owa24gdHDrJrKC6TA0skCA9oo8QNgejblD+deKw6EB6PAShW07fth24E8ECMnqGum+Sp2dUgF0qMHZsANqbQAutd+YKwG-uB8S0fksUmcwDHadByHMDxxbxAvaR70l1UEl0YDzEO19tEcfRCOMeMyNw2xmHSYj4yifXcy0VJzcyeMckKWjZzU+C0WafL0i6TchkgMZpnmUgVm2Q5zmqLObmJQDQleVEg1+QBi5Bc41zY+Fzx40lsuE5TCVkwTMKU0UmWX6iR65S0+XM4VYkbVSqcwZMyXmVg6roQalhF+0VgGClFuHcWyoJSV3JlCYa5F96KWVkFNW01kAABE7gsGWjYYMYgsD1HcNQDoyFk5ez2gdYyuABaQSfKoMOw5I4KW2sw32RZt6hD+lUfhPtWEjm3meURzhxEsKOjvUo28FyyJIPIwRqhYxOXwqUNRxBFpoCWgpJO1ZbrsJ-HOSuZc3rYMrg3H6qhu6t2Bh3auTda7t1YtXASw8e59zcWDLRTi-GtzHrMCeuCorqWHsNBeBkjImTMpZGy9kdFKNck1HBnlvLTxiafPCqgExTyvmFB4t9olykfnPUmlSYqpXhFTLKP8sR-yZizIBwsQEri5sQHmoofBQLKLhRqwS4ExIQR1YcKC8SSz6gpDBtA57YKVgQU4QA)

Comment: This is probably worth creating another question: Why are your solutions with "indexed access" and "distributive conditional types" functions with one call signature and one implementation signature? This construct of just one call signature and one implementation signature seems odd in general and not the purpose of overloaded functions. I don't understand why I get an error if a constraint generic type parameter is used directly in the function implementation instead of using this function overloading construct with just one call signature.

Comment: For my issue at hand, I picked function overloading as a means to relate specific input parameter types to specific return types. I don't have to use function overloading if there are better solutions out there to solve my issue. However, the solutions of "indexed access" and "distributive conditional types" seem to require this function overloading construct of one call signature (with a constraint generic type) and one implementation signature (which contains non-generic types). At least I get errors like e.g. `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`.

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904247/implementing-a-generic-function-with-a-conditional-return-type ... you can use single-call-signature overloads to get some looser type checking of the implementation than you would without it.

Comment: "write a single generic call signature" ... why does this need to be written as an overload, instead of the base function signature?

Comment: Try it and find out!

Answer (score 9):

```
function foo(options: "a"): "a";
function foo(options: "b"): "b";
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b" {
```

The last line is the start of the implementation of the function, but it's not part of the type that's visible to the external world. So with the code you wrote, passing in something of type `"a" | "b"` isn't actually allowed. Just `"a"` or `"b"` on their own.

The error message probably included the following text, which tries to point out the problem, though it may be hard to understand what it means if you've never seen it before:

> The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.

The fix is to add one more overload to the definition:

```
function foo(options: "a"): "a";
function foo(options: "b"): "b";
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b";
function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b" {
```

Comment: Of course, adding a third call signature `function foo(options: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b";` is a solution to get rid of the compiler error, but it's not the solution I had in mind. I'm sorry I didn't explicitly mention it as an additional solution I already found in my question.
My function should only allow an "a" or a "b" and is not intended to expect the union of both. I only picked the union in my implementation because I wanted to keep my implementation's signature as specific as possible. I could've also used `string` instead.
My question actually refers to the one @jcalz deduced.

Comment: See "you could decide to write a single generic call signature" in jcalz' answer to do it in 2 lines instead of 4.